# Fill empty values with forecast.linear in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with increasing numbers and I want with forecast.linear to predict the missing values between the previous values and the next value. G2:G6 AND G16.
However when I run the FORECAST.LINEAR(F14,G2:G13,F2:F13) it outputs 1.60 which is not correct if you consider that it should be something greater than 1.62 and less than 1.89

[image]

UPDATE:
I did this calculation and it seems ok

```
=IF(AND(G2=0;G3=0;G4<>0;G1<>0)=TRUE;ROUND((G4-G1)/3;2);FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct linear progression for the values your sample shows for 4/1/21 through 15/1/21 should be 1.60424.  The final value, 1.62, happens to be a high outlier that is above the linear best fit for the values given.  So the function is working correctly.  It would not be uncommon for the first or last points to be above or below the linear progression.

The problem is that the function’s range of known Y values ends with 1.62, so the function you entered knows nothing of the 1.89 value.

When I set the problem up to skip a 13th and 14th x and y, but include a 15th value 1.89, I get 1.61 and 1.74 for values 13 and 14, so even when including the 1.89 value, the 13th value is still less than 1.62.  It’s a significantly high variation from the linear.

I’m not sure what the best approach is, but this will not likely be an easy problem to solve using this approach.  You end up with a circular reference if the Y value you are trying to forecast is within the known Y values range of the formula.  The normal way of solving this problem is to have separate actual columns and forecast columns, and not mix the two

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this process, but then in a separate range sort the data in the opposite direction and repeat? This would fill in the range from the other direction... You'd then need to merge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).